# `bjam --toolset=` and tag values for Apple compilers?

Tags: xcode, boost, bjam

When building Boost binary libraries with `bjam`, one may specify which compiler to use, *without* specifying a particular compiler version, by using certain values for the `--toolset=` option.  For example:

`bjam --with-serialization --toolset=msvc`

the **toolset value** `msvc` tells `bjam` to search your system for *some* version of Microsoft Visual C++ and then use it to build a number of variants of the Boost.Serialization library.  The resulting libraries will contain a tag indicating which toolset was actually used.  For example, the above command creates files such as:

```
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-s-1_44.lib
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-sgd-1_44.lib
...
```

where the string `vc100` in the filename is a **toolset tag** indicating that the *Microsoft Visual C++ 2010* compiler version was found and used to build the libraries. [More details about Boost library file naming conventions can be found [here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming)]

One may specify also a *specific* version of a compiler using certain other values for the `--toolset=` option.  For example:

`bjam --with-serialization --toolset=msvc-9.0`

tells `bjam` that, even though I may have several compilers on my system, I want it to specifically use *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008*.  The resulting libraries contain the tag string `vc90` to indicate that *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008* was used to build them.

The Boost documentation seems to be a bit out-of-date with respect to newer compilers on the Mac (e.g., how does one distinguish between GCC, LLVM-GCC and LLVM?)

My question is, what are some of the other `bjam --toolset=` values and their corresponding tags for ***specific compiler versions*** in Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 on the Mac (*not* the general compiler name values like `darwin`)?  Are these documented anywhere?  Even if building Boost libraries with some versions is not yet supported by Boost, have the `toolset` and tag values been specified yet?

Please help replace the `???`s in this table:

```
TOOL AND VERSION               --toolset=     TAG
======================================================
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008      msvc-9.0       vc90
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010      msvc-10.0      vc100
Apple (1) GCC 4.0 (2)            ???          xgcc40
Apple GCC 4.2                    ???          xgcc42
Apple LLVM GCC 4.2               ???           ???
Apple LLVM compiler 1.5 (2)      ???           ???
Apple LLVM compiler 2.0 (3)      ???           ???
```

(1) Apple produces their own versions of the GCC and LLVM compilers to add Apple-specific extensions and behavior.

(2) Available in Xcode 3 only.

(3) Available in Xcode 4 only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a direct mapping from the toolset specified to the base part of the tag. Hence for any Apple Xcode compiler that you specify that uses the `darwin.jam` toolset the start of the tag will always be `xgcc` (for Xcode GCC). The second part, i.e the version number of the compiler, is usually automatically discovered from the compiler itself. The `darwin.jam` toolset code uses the `-dumnpversion` option to discover what that version is (see [darwin.jam](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/tools/build/v2/tools/darwin.jam#L123) line #123). So a few things:

1. For Xcode it will always be `toolset=darwin` for the default `g++`.
2. For other non-default versions you have to set up a `site-config.jam` or `user-config.jam` to tell Boost Build where and which are the compilers you have (see the [BB Configuration](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html) docs).
3. The `toolset=darwin-<some_version>` matches what you specify in your configuration.
4. The `darwin.jam` toolset supports smart selection of the compiler based on what you are trying to build to make it a bit easier.

For example I use something like the following for iOS development:

```
using darwin : : /Xcode-path/usr/bin/g++-4.0 ;
using darwin : : /Xcode-path/usr/bin/g++-4.2 ;
using darwin : 4.2~iphone
:   /Xcode-path/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch armv6
:   <striper>
:   <architecture>arm <target-os>iphone
;
using darwin : 4.2~iphonesim
:   /Xcode-path/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
:   <striper>
:   <architecture>x86 <target-os>iphone
;
```

For which I can:

1. `bjam toolset=darwin-4.0` -- For a regular OSX build with GCC 4.0. Which results in the tag `xgcc-42`.
2. `bjam toolset=darwin-4.2` -- Similarly for OSX and GCC 4.2. For which I would get a tag of `xgcc-42`.
3. `bjam toolset-darwin architecture=arm target-os=iphone` -- To do an iPhone device build with GCC 4.2. The tag ends up also being `xgcc42` which is a collision. But there's a limit to how much we can account for in those tags. And it's usually not a problem because one segregates built results across platforms anyway.

You might set up using one of the LLVM compilers by adding to your configuration:

```
using darwin : 4.2~llvm~gcc : /Xcode-path/user/bin/llvm-g++ ;
```

And invoke with `bjam toolset=darwin-4.2~llvm~gcc`. Unfortunately the tag would also be `xgcc-4.2` (as again, it's based on using `darwin.jam`). So you would need to segregate the resulting libs from the other GCC builds.

Also unfortunate is that there isn't a documented location of mapping the toolset used to the tag value other than in code (see the BB [common.jam](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/tools/common.jam#L801-L841) lines #801 to #841).

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Note that no modifications are necessary to any `.jam` files to use `--toolset=darwin-4.0` or `--toolset=darwin-4.2`.  I've updated the table in the question to include these and their associated tags.

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon.  Although one can use, say, `--toolset=darwin-4.2` to generate a library with the tag `xgcc42` this does not guarantee that Apple's GCC 4.2 was actually used.  Table in original question updated to reflect this.

Comment: Right.. Boost Build tries to be forgiving and will build with what it can find given the information. So for anything other than the default `g++` you have to set up a configuration file. You could fill in the second column for Xcode as `darwin-/user-configured/`. And for the third column At minimum LLVM GCC will produce an `xgcc42` tag.